# MYSQL query for returning records in 1 minute interval

Tags: mysql

have problem returning records by 1 minute interval. For example `2016-12-17 21:38` I need to return only 1 minute interval beetwen `2016-12-17 21:37` and `2016-12-17 21:38`. But I noticed it return beetween `2016-12-17 20:00` - all time bigger `2016-12-17 21:38`

Where can problem be ?

```
SELECT * FROM appointments 
WHERE id_user = 84 
AND hash = 'new' 
AND end_datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

end_datetime - datetime in mysql

Comment: there are no minutes between 37 and 38; you need to use seconds.

Comment: if I change 60 SECOND it's still returning same results or 2 MINUTE, 10 MINUTE, 100 MINUTE, still same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments 
WHERE id_user = 84 
AND hash = 'new' 
AND end_datetime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AND NOW()
```

Answer (score -1):

Below query should work:

```
SELECT * FROM appointment
WHERE end_date > DATE(curtime()-INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1465/2/0)**.

Comment: weird. time now - 2016-12-17 22:44 , with your code it returns records with end_datetime 2016-12-17 21:20:00 and 2016-12-18 00:00:00. And i have 3 records. 1 don't show, time 2016-12-17 18:00:00